# Cohort on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to do cohort on tableau? how would I see cohort of first time purchase if I only have name of customer, date of sign up, date of first time purchase. I want to see the relation between sign up and purchase on cohort.

company_name   signup_date   approval_status   approval_date   first_paid_plan   first_paid_plan_date

Comment: Hi Ahmed, If you do a quick search, you will see a lot of examples. Tableau even has one posted in their knowledge base. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll like what you find here: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to explore what else is possible with LODs while you are on the page :)